# multiple CSS only show/hide button (no java/jquery)

Tags: html, css

I need code for a joke website i am trying to make, which uses a show/hide button to reveal content/hide content.

it starts off hidden, and then there is a button to change it.

however, it cannot contain any javascript, or jquery, as this is an assesment for school project i am doing (which is on css mainly)

is it possible to have multiple? i have only achieved one so far.

my code so far (i got it off of this website http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-showhide ):
(html)

```
<article>
    <input type="checkbox" id="RMa" role="button">
    <label for="RMa" onclick=""><span>Show</span><span>Hide</span></label>     

    <section>
        <p>Joke</p>
    </section>    
    <section>
        <p>Punchline</p>
    </section>

</article>
```

(css)

```
article {
position: relative;
}

article:before, :after {
display: table;
}

article:after { clear: both     }

article section:last-of-type {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}

 input[type=checkbox] {
width: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
}

[for="read_more"] {
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
width: ;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

[for="read_more"]:hover {
background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

[for="read_more"]  span:last-of-type {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}

 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~  section {
display: block;
visibility: visible;
width: 100%;
}

 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~  figure { width: 100%     }

 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"]  span:first-of-type {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}

 input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"]  span:last-of-type {
display: block;
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: The 2nd comment on the website you linked says how someone else applied this to multiple entries. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @FuzzBall007 No i havent, thanks for realizing that!

Comment: good job! how does it work?

Comment: Better u can use it the same name for multiple label and checkbox and position it...

Comment: @Kermani it works greak! all you need to do is change read_more into any name, plus change that in the css and add that class name in front of the input tag (so its not confused wit the other buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You used `input[type=checkbox]` for see if the checkbox is selected and you should use an ID, that way you can check for each one and not for all of them, for example:

```
#first[type="checkbox"] { 
  /* Code here */
}

#second[type="checkbox"] {
  /* Code here */
}
```